# Problema com conexão SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server

Tenho um sistema PHP hospedado em um servidor Linux que faz consultas a um banco SQL Server através do `mssql`. Funciona perfeitamente no servidor. Precisei fazer algumas alterações neste sistema, então o coloquei no meu localhost e estava funcionando ok. Do nada, as consultas com `mssql` pararam de funcionar, retornando `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` nas páginas.

A conexão:

```
$host='******';
$user='***';
$database='****';
$pass='****';

$con=mssql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die ("Erro de conexão com o banco de dados"); 
mssql_select_db("$database") or die ("Erro ao selecionar banco de dados");
```

A conexão não retorna nenhum erro. Porém quando executo alguma query, como esta:

```
 $sql=mssql_query("SELECT DES_MOVIMENTO, VAL_PRODUTO_MOVIMENTO
 FROM supervisor.MOVIMENTO_ESTOQUE 
 WHERE COD_PRODUTO='1254'") 
 or die ('Erro de conexão com o SIGA');
```

Aparece este erro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O PHP INFO mostra estas diretivas:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: No localhost, habilite os erros no PHP, provavelmente o erro não tem a ver com a conexão com o banco de dados.

Comment: Os erros estão habilitados.

Comment: Existe alguma outra página do localhost sem conexão com o banco de dados? Se sim, ela funciona?

Comment: Única coisa que achei foi isso, nunca usei mssql então não sei dizer se é útil: http://sakrawebstudio.blogspot.com.br/2012/05/mssqlquery-cause-neterremptyresponse-in.html

Comment: @FilipeMoraes, todas as outras funcionam. Apenas as páginas com consultas mssql não funcionam. Consultas ao Mysql funcionam normal.

Comment: @DH., ja tentei isso, não deu :(

Comment: Utiliza algum programa para recriar o sistema local, como o Wamp? Utiliza windows?

Comment: Utilizo Linux Fedora com Apache. Já consegui resolver, reinstalei o módulo php-mssql. Após reinstalar funcionou. Obrigada a todos que ajudaram.

Comment: Cria uma resposta com os detalhes que resolveram o problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema foi solucionado reinstalando o módulo php-mssql no meu servidor local.